# ITMS-90428: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswift_Concurrency.dylib don’t match

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new build of my app from the new Xcode 14.1 RC but it keeps failing with the below error:

> ITMS-90428: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswift_Concurrency.dylib don’t match
> /Payload/MY_APP.app/MY_APP_WatchOS.app/libswift_Concurrency.dylib.
> Make sure the files are correct, rebuild your app, and resubmit it.
> Don’t apply post-processing to /Payload/MY_APP.app/MY_APP_WatchOS.app/libswift_Concurrency.dylib.

My bundle contains a watchOS 4.3 app which I thought might have been an issue, so I tried increasing it to watchOS 7.0 but still got the error.

Bitcode is disabled for all targets.
I don't think I have any post-processing enabled either as I just use the standard Xcode submit to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here.
I changed nothing in my watch app since the last successful upload.
The only change is Xcode 14.0 -> 14.1.

Comment: The Solution from @Darren `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = NO` doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: Raising the Deployment Target to watchOS 8.0 fixed the Problem for me.

Comment: Xcode 14.1 RC2 fixes the problem. (Check the Release Notes)

Answer (score 0):

Success.

I finally got a build to be accepted.

I set `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = NO` for the watch target.

I don't know how this might affect the actual running of the watch app, as I no longer have an Apple Watch to test it on, but the iOS app is running fine through TestFlight.